# How to skip a specific character while locating a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm very new to R so my question might come out as dumb but I hope I can find an answer here.
I am trying to locate specific patterns in a given number of sequences. Unfortunately, these sequences have gaps, shown as "-", which causes my patterns not to match correctly. Is there any way possible to skip over this "-" character while looking for a specific pattern in R?

My ultimate goal is to detect the position of two residues in the sequence without losing the position of where the gaps are so I can't use !grep to extract just the residues and exclude gaps.

For a simplified version, my sequence might look like "Q---ASV-S" (note, the number of "-" may vary from example to example). I need the output to be able to find the positions of Q and the second S while taking into account the number of gaps between them. So output should be start = 1, end = 9.

```
My_seq <- "Q---ASV-S"
str_locate(My_seq, "QASVS")
#Does not find the pattern
Seq_modified <- gsub("\\-", "-?", My_seq)
str_locate(Seq_modified, "QASVS")
#Does not find the pattern`
```

Sorry for the confusing question. It is my first time using this platform so please let me know if there is anyway I can make the question more clear.

p.s. the other questions that I have looked at use Regex but I am not very familiar with that and don't think that I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
str_locate(My_seq, "Q(-)*A(-)*S(-)*V(-)*S")
```

The `(-)*` part means it will match any number of dashes (including 0)